Gnome extensions not showing in manager
I restored my gnome extensions to a new PC and restored my dconf and all my extensions and gnome settings have been restored but in the extensions manager none of my extensions are showing in the installed section and all extensions I browse say unsupported (even though they are literally installed on my system right now).
I click 'use extensions' in the manager and every time I exit the manager it deactivates. I run
gnome-shell version

And get
Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.9) as a Wayland display server
Failed to setup: Could not take control: GDBus.Error:System.Error.EBUSY: Device or resource busy

I am on the latest Linux Mint. All my extensions are running perfectly which is weird.
